# Django i18n_patterns - How to prevent prefixing of non-active languages

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

In my django settings.py file, I have six active languages:

```
LANGUAGES = (
('de', gettext_noop('German')),
('en', gettext_noop('English')),
('es', gettext_noop('Spanish')),
('fr', gettext_noop('French')),
('nl', gettext_noop('Dutch')),
('pt', gettext_noop('Portuguese')),
)
```

These pages work great when using i18n patterns:

```
 http://exmaple.com/de/main
 http://exmaple.com/nl/main
 etc...
```

However, if you search my site in Google, you'll see multiple pages for language prefixes. Some for languages that I don't support. Some of which don't even exist:

```
http://examble.com/ch/main
http://exmaple.com/zz/main
etc..
```

I'm not sure why these pages are getting indexed. They aren't in my sitemap. However, Django does serve them as pages.

Question, what is the best way to modify i18n_patterns so that it only allows valid, active languages as defined in settings.py? I would like all other 2 char prefixes to 404.

Comment: do you use a cms for those pages and if yes which one ?

Comment: also what version do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution(I know) is to use [solid-i18n-urls](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls).

Install the package:

```
pip install solid_i18n
```

Modify settings a little bit:

```
# Default language, that will be used for requests without language prefix
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

# supported languages
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
)

# enable django translation
USE_I18N = True

#Add SolidLocaleMiddleware instead of LocaleMiddleware to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'solid_i18n.middleware.SolidLocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

Use solid_i18n_patterns instead of i18n_patterns

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from solid_i18n.urls import solid_i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = solid_i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^main/$', 'about.view', name='about'),
)
```

Now, if you go to `example.com/en/main` it works fine as `en` is specified in your languages linst but if you go to `example.com/ch/main` it throws a 404 page not found error.

Comment: Sorry @ChillarAnand. I believe you do not understand my question or do not understand what solid il8n does. 

In your example above, I would want www.example.com/es/main to show a 404 instead of a 200. Solid i8ln does not do that for you. Verified by testing you code on my site.

Comment: @keithhackbarth Correct me if am wrong. Using above procedure, i made a working example that suits your requirements. Just clone, install requirements, run server thats it. https://github.com/ChillarAnand/django-internationalization-example .

Comment: I sincerely apologize, after testing your example, I got it to work. My problem was that I hadn't removed the pre-existing 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' from the settings file. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: As of Django 1.10 this can be done without solid-i18n-urls.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution, but may help you or point you to a good solution.

- *What about a custom middleware ?*

Here we have 2 options:

1. A middleware where you check the country of the user and redirect to your allowed countries (If the user country  is not allowed, you can redirect to a custom url or show a 404 error)
2. A middleware where you check the url-path of the client, so you will have `/country_code/url` and you can do as above, if the path is not allowed you can redirect to a custom url or show a 404 error

Little examples:

## 1. A middleware to check country

**pygeoIP** is used in the example to get country by ip

```
import pygeoip

class CountryMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        allowed_countries = ['GB','ES', 'FR']  # Add your allowed countries
        gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat', pygeoip.MEMORY_CACHE)
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        user_country = gi.country_code_by_addr(ip)

        if user_country not in allowed_countries:
            return HttpResponse... # Here you decide what to do if the url is not allowed
            # Show 404 error
            # or Redirect to other page...
```

## 2. A middleware to check url

```
class DomainMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        """Parse out the subdomain from the request"""        
        # You especify full path or root paths
        # If you specify '/en' as allowed paths, '/en/whatever' are allowed
        ALLOWED_PATHS = ['/en','/fr', '/es']  # You add here allowed paths'
        path = request.path
        can_access = False
        for url in ALLOWED_PATHS:  # Find if the path is an allowed url 
            if url in path:  # If any allowed url is in path
                can_access=True
                break

        if not can_access:  # If user url is not allowed
            return HttpResponse... # Here you decide what to do if the url is not allowed
            # Show 404 error
            # or Redirect to other page...
```

---

If you decide to use any of this options you have to remember:

- You need to add middleware files in the path `your_project/middleware/middlewarefile.py`
- You need to add middlewares on your settings.py:

  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

  ```
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  # etc.....
  'yourproject.middleware.domainmiddleware.DomainMiddleware',
  ```

  )
- The code I showed here is not completed or tested, it's an orientation to help you find a good soluiton